# vim: symbol lookup error: vim: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsEncodedString

Tags: python, vim

Today I encountered a problem about vim:

vim: symbol lookup error: vim: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsEncodedString

I didn't install any vim plugins. But I installed some Python projects(Nginx, uwsgi). Seemingly after these installations, vim crushed.

Any clues?

Comment: It looks like the Python shared library that exists on your system doesn't match the one your Vim has been compiled against any more.

Comment: I have no idea about this problem. So I reinstalled vim reluctantly.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same problem. Here is my solution.

Type in terminal

```
ldd /usr/bin/vim
```

it showed that the python lib pointing to a location customized by me.

```
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /home/ql/software/vtk/vtkpython-7.0.0-Linux-64bit/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f303b99c000)
```

I opened my *.bashrc*, finding something related to the above line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ql/software/vtk/vtkpython-7.0.0-Linux-64bit/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then I commented the above line out.

Open a new terminal and type again:

```
ldd /usr/bin/vim
```

It can be noticed that the python lib points to some location other than that in the previous result:

```
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f1ed4a36000)
```

Now vim runs.

Answer (score 2):

This might not directly answer the question, but I had the same problem when loading anaconda and found that invoking vi, instead of vim worked. Since I'm guessing that vi is symlinked to vim because syntax highlighting worked and my ~/.vimrc commands all work as expected.

It's a simple and inelegant option, but perhaps this might work for others too.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you are using a different python version in your machine compared to the one vim is compiled in.

For eg. If you are in a virtualenv, try deactivating it and then use vim.

Comment: How to know which python does vim to link? I execute `ldd /usr/bin/vim | grep python`, no result.

Answer (score 1):

the problem can also occur when you point the library path to another path BY exporting to environment mentioning in .bash.rc  .
Probably can happen when you are changing the paths for oracle installations. 
So correct your Paths so that vim would be pointing to the correct lib  path